# How to change favicon angular.js

Tags: angularjs, html

I am attempting to change my favicon in an angular.js application.  I am running into an issue of not understanding how the icon is being referenced.  My code is as such.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>AngularAugma 1.0</title>
  <base href="/">



  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body id="top-of-page">
  <app-root><div class="loading"></div></app-root>


</body>
```

When I tried changing the link for the favicon to the following (and several other directory variations) I got the default icon (blank page img).

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="app/img/icons8-shopping-basket-96.png">
```

Here's where my confusion really kicks.  To check to see if I was misunderstanding something fundamental I placed the favicon into a directory (simply to test the scope of the href link) and without changing the original href link that img still appeared.  How is this happening and how to do I properly reference another image?

Comment: The browser will cache the favicon. If you change it, open your browser's developer tools, make sure caching is disabled, then reload the page to make the browser download the new icon.

Comment: thank you, do you have any ideas on what is prevent the non-.ico image from working?

Comment: I think you need use ../app/img/ or /img/icons8-shopping-basket-96.png please provide directory structure

Comment: @JS Ford I don't think so  this cause any problem, If he is using AngularCLI then for every change it will compile page automatically